# Deleting/ modifying file contents from phpstorm changes group of the file in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpstorm

I am logged in as "user" in Ubuntu 12.04 
In my "project" directory i have created a file `query.sql`. This file has permission like below.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  946 Dec  2 17:51 query.sql
```

This file should be web writable. So i ran this command.

```
sudo chown :www-data query.sql
```

Now the permission is

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user www-data  946 Dec  2 17:51 query.sql
```

If i modify content of `query.sql` from phpstorm, group is set again as `user`. Like:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  937 Dec  2 17:57 query.sql
```

If i modify `query.sql` content using other editor like `gedit` this problem do not happen.

IDE Version: 8.0.1
Build: 138.2001

Comment: IDE version? See if `Use "safe write"` is enabled -- disabling it should help (`Settings` and then use search box and search for "safe").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find and disable `Use "safe write"` option:

1. Settings (Preferences on Mac)
2. Using search box (top left corner) search for `safe`

With this option **enabled** (by default) the new temp file is created first and then renamed to the correct name -- this will cause the behaviour you have descried (as technically it will be brand new file at the end). **When disabled**, file will be rewritten in place so no changes to permissions/ownership.

**P.S.**
PhpStorm v8.0.2 (builds on 139.xxx branch) has restructured settings screen. The full path to that option is now `Settings | Appearance & Behaviour | System Settings --> Use "safe write"`

Comment: You can use `ctr + shift + a` to bring up option context menu which will search for required setting  (by typing `safe write`) and then easily change it